# Can I disable exceptions for when a pure virtual function is called?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some code that looks like this:

```
class Writable {
public:
    virtual void putc(const char ch) = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~Writable() {};
};

class Readable {
public:
    virtual char getc() = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~Readable() {};
};
```

Notice the two virtual functions. Compiling this (along with my other code) using `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, and linking with `-fno-exceptions` produces this output:

```
arm-none-eabi-size  --format=berkeley bareCortexM.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 108948    2304    2372  113624   1bbd8 bareCortexM.elf
```

Running it again with method stubs in place of pure virtual functions yields:

```
arm-none-eabi-size  --format=berkeley bareCortexM.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  47340    2296     304   49940    c314 bareCortexM.elf
```

This huge difference seems to be due to exceptions. Is there any way that I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is described by this blog post: [Smaller binary size with C++ on baremetal (g++)](http://elegantinvention.com/blog/information/smaller-binary-size-with-c-on-baremetal-g/)

> #### Provide a `__cxa_pure_virtual()` implementation
>
> If you use pure virtual functions anywhere but have disabled exceptions, you may
>   notice your code suddenly inflate again.
>
> This happened to me, and it took a while to track down, whoops!
>   Inspecting assembly listing of the final binary (from `objdump -h -C -S`), it looked like exceptions
>   were coming back!
>
> One thing I tried was linking with `-nostdlib`, completely pulling libstdc++ out of
>   the picture. I provided dummy implementations of malloc, realloc,
>   free, and a few other stdlib functions I used, but then `avr32-g++`
>   complained about something I hadn’t seen before: I was missing
>   `__cxa_pure_virtual()`.
>
> “*Aha*,” I thought, “*this has to be it!*” In the source of that
>   particular function, found in libstdc++, is a call to
>   `std::terminate()`, [seen
>   here](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_4_4_3_release/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/pure.cc). That call threw a lovely party all over my poor AVR32′s
>   flash memory, trampling on `-fno-exceptions` on their way in.
>
> Anyway, `__cxa_pure_virtual()` is what actually gets called when you
>   call a pure virtual function. Like `new` and `delete`,
>   this is probably something you want to override anyway so your own
>   debug/trace code can give you useful feedback. The implementation is
>   straightforward, just be sure to make it `extern "C"` so the name doesn’t get mangled:
>
> ```
> extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual() { while(1); }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but implementing **__cxa_pure_virtual** does not help me.

But solution for me was add **-fno-rtti** beside **-fno-exceptions** option.