# Operator Delete in an Abstract Class, how does it work

Tags: c++, abstract-class, delete-operator

how this thing works.

```
class Car
{
 public:
 Car() = default; 
 Car(const Car& other) = delete; 
 Car& operator=(const Car& other) = delete; 
 virtual void WhatsTheMake() = 0; 
 virtual void WhatsTheSpeed() =0; 
}
```

Now what does this **delete** keyword mean here?

Also does using abstract class increase code size. I mean if I don't need an Abstract class, do I always have to create it ?

Comment: They are [*deleted functions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions).

Comment: If you don't need to use it so yes, obviously it would be redundant. about **delete** - it means you explicitly delete function definition

Answer (score 1):

If you mark a function as deleted ( = delete), any use of it will generate a compile error.

Regarding the code size, actually yes, defining an abstract class will generated more code for managing the pure virtual call ([Declaring abstract class (pure virtual method) increase binary size substantially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946912/declaring-abstract-class-pure-virtual-method-increase-binary-size-substantiall))

Personally I use an abstract class when I need to define a common base interface and I don't want to provide any common implementation and I want to delegate the implementation to the concrete classes which will inherit from (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping)